# PresentModalViewController: Where to release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

To use presentModalViewController I must `alloc` and `initWithNibName:bundle:` a view. My question is: where do I release it? Does the `dismissModalViewController:animated:` handle the release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you allocatet and initialized it, than you have to release it. Do it like this:

```
YourViewController *controller = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

PresentModalViewController:animated: increases automatically the retainCount. And as soon as the controller disappeared from the view, it will release the controller. And so the controller will be deallocated. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can release after you present the controller; the presenting controller (its parent) will retain your modal controller.